# Problema con funcion show de rutas resource LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, function, show

despues de mucho buscar por google y no dar con una solución a mi problema he decidido preguntar a la sabiduría de internet:

**Estas son mis rutas:**

```
Route::get('/customers', 'CustomerController@index')
->name('customerIndex');
Route::get('/customers/create', 'CustomerController@create')
->name('customerCreate');
Route::post('/customers', 'CustomerController@store')
->name('customerStore');
Route::get('/customers/{customer}', 'CustomerController@show')
->name('customerShow');
Route::get('/customers/{customer}/edit', 'CustomerController@edit')
->name('customerEdit');
Route::put('/customers/{customer}', 'CustomerController@update')
->name('customerUpdate');
Route::delete('/customers/{customer}', 'CustomerController@destroy')
->name('customerDestroy');
```

**Antes tenia:**

```
Route::resource('customers', 'CustomerController');
```

El caso es que la ruta que va a la función show no hace nada, cualquier código que ponga dentro de esa función no se ejecuta.

**La funcion show:**

```
public function show($id)
{
    dd("hola");
    $customer = Customer::findOrFail($id);

    return view('customers.show', compact('customer'));

}
```

Alguien sabria decirme porque ni siquiera se ejecuta el dd('hola'); 
Un detalle importante, a la vista si que llega, pero no porque lo ponga en el return de la función, porque si lo quito se sigue viendo la vista.

Gracias desde ya.

Comment: me causa duda que a la url le pasas una variable `customer` pero luego en el método me pasas un parámetro `$id` no deberían ser el mismo en ambos casos?

Comment: en un principio creo que da igual como se llamen en cada lado mientras sea el mismo dato y lo trates para lo mismo, en este caso un id de customer para buscar y hacer referencia a ese customer

Comment: No da igual pues son nombres de variables y deben coincidir

Comment: sigo pensando que si da igual, ya solucione el error y no era eso. Revisando archivos me di cuenta que tenia el controlador duplicado y yo estaba trabajando con uno y laravel con otro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gracias por las respuestas, ya solucione el error.

Tenia dos controladores que usaban la misma clase de controlador y yo estaba trabajando con uno y laravel con otro.

Answer (score 0):

tal vez tienes otra ruta que causa conflicto.

Si no es asi, intenta limpiando el cache:

```
php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Una de las maneras mas faciles de acceder a el controlador con los recursos que trae laravel por defecto es con

`Route::resource('customers','CustomerController');`

de este modo seria el codigo del metodo show

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $customer = Customer::findOrFail($id);

        return view('customers.show', compact('customer'));
```

Recuerda que debes tener definidos bien tus modelos ya que estas usando eloquent y por lo menos si algo anda mal, debió enviarte un error

y recuerda que para acceder al metodo `show` debiste a ver definido antes un boton o enlace

`@foeach($customer as $c)
<a href="{{ route('customers.show', $c->id) }}">
@endforeach`